# How to cleanly stop m2e cargo:run from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, cargo, m2e

Using the run mojo from the cargo-maven2-plugin I would like to know of a better way to shut down the container.

The console output says Ctrl+C to stop, but that seems to do nothing.

If I terminate, it leaves an orphan java.exe process that I have to kill myself.

Am I doing something wrong? This is a little cumbersome.

Edit: I am usign Tomcat in a standalone config. If I use embedded Jetty, naturally terminate works, however we need Tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> thing seems to be a known [Eclipse/Jetty issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-208). The last post says that issuing `mvn cargo:stop` would stop an already running container, however it doesn't work for me—albeit, I've only made some quick test a with an archetype generated webapp.

Using *Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 (20110916-0149)* if I issue `mvn cargo:run` and wait for the container to boot (for now it's Jetty, no configurations; let's see if you can get it working like this) clicking on the big red *Terminate* button kills the running process and no lingering `java{,w}.exe` are left behind.

I don't know how do you issue `mvn cargo:run` from Eclipse right now, but maybe you're using it as an *External Tool* (and that's why a process is left behind). If you have m2eclipse installed you should create Maven run configurations for it like this:

```
Run --> Run Configurations --> Maven build --> right click --> New
```

It should be straightforward from here on.

<sub>(I've found two Eclipse bug tickets ([here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159803) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016)) that seems to be related to Eclipse's inability to read a *healthy* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> via it's console.)</sub>

---

I've verified that when I'm starting an external Tomcat (7.0.23) instance with `mvn cargo:run` from Eclipse via the m2e plugin (after the container have started) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> indeed doesn't work.

After this I've ran `mvn cargo:run` from my Cygwin console. The result was the same.

Finally I've tried it from Windows's *cmd* and it worked.

My guess is that this is a bug in the `cargo-maven-plugin`.

Running `mvn cargo:stop` from either Eclipse or Cygwin did the trick for me.

You can run the cargo plugin from Eclipse by creating a `Maven build` Run or Debug configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: I am using the Maven build configuration. The difference I've noticed is that when you use Jetty, it is Embedded and I don't think I recall *seeing* a java.exe -- whereas if I use Tomcat, I used a non-embedded install (inside the target dir though which I think is default) and that is where the extra java.exe process comes from. The issue you linked does capture the problem in the context of clicking terminate. Maybe I'm wrong. I will take a look again when I return to work on Wednesday.

Comment: I am going to award you this bounty if only because you are the only one who attempted to provide info and it is a good starting place. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Doug *I will take a look again when I return to work on Wednesday.* I was waiting for just that. So, in the end it didn't worked I guess. I'll take a quick look (I have a Tomcat installation at home—where I'm at right now). Just a small remark: it doesn't look like an _Eclipse_ issue at this point.

Comment: My experience is that you should always run `cargo:run` (or indeed any other Windows program that expects Ctrl-C) from `cmd`. There is more background on this thread comment on the mintty wiki: https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c14

Comment: How do you issue `mvn cargo:run` or `mvn cargo:stop` from Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this bug appears from Cygwin on windows, but not the normal windows command window

Answer (score 0):

In general if you run Cargo using an Eclipse Maven launcher in DEBUG mode (i.e. Debug as --> Maven build...), killing the process on the Eclipse console (the red button) doesn't leave any orphan process...

I don't know why, but it works :) At least on my workspace